# Sort Multidimensional Array in VB.NET

Tags: .net, arrays, string, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a 2X50 array like this-

```
R-125212,11
C-254645,25
R-456598,96
M-456878,35
O-980857,89
And so on...
```

Now I want to sort this array with the values of the 2nd Column. So the output should look like-

```
R-125212,11
C-254645,25
M-456878,35
O-980857,89
R-456598,96
And so on...
```

How to do this with VB.NET easily? If there is other better way to have the similar result without using array, that also will help me.

Comment: What do the values actually mean? Would it make more sense to use a class?

Comment: The second column of the array (If we consider that like a table) holds only integers. I want to sort the array in descending order of the values of the 2nd column

Comment: So what's the first column?

Comment: That holds string, if changing the datatype to integer will allow me to sort easily, I can do that.

Comment: The type is irrelevant.. Is it a unique identifier? If so, then make a class and you can just sort on a property

Comment: As I see it you have `Char` - `Integer` , `Integer`. and you want to sort by the second column

Comment: Yes, it is unique. Can you please help me with code? I am not that good in programming.

Comment: How about you answer the question that was asked? Noone asked what the data types are (at least they hadn't when I started typing this).  The question was what that data actually represents.  The reason is that your data would almost certainly be better represented by a 1D array or collection of objects of a type that has three properties.  Sorting is then as simple as calling a single method.

Comment: @3vts You are right.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The first column represents Student ID and the 2nd column is their marks

Comment: So, is there a reason that you can't define a type with properties for those two values and then create an array or collection of instances of that type? There are times when it is appropriate to use a 2D array but this is not one of them. If this is a homework assignment and you have to use a 2D array then I suggest that you don't cheat by getting others to do your homework for you.  If you don't have to use a 2D array then I suggest that you don't.

Comment: By the way, how is that a 3x2 array?  I see two "columns" but not three "rows".

Comment: @jmcilhinney 3x2 was typing mistake. And it is not a homework.

Comment: Then I would strongly suggest not using a 2D array.  It is appropriate to use a 2D array for a matrix, i.e. when every element is a peer.  That is not the case here so a 2D array is inappropriate.  If the data is coming from a database then using a `DataTable`, as suggested in the answer below, is likely to be your best bet.  Otherwise, define a type to represent one record and then create a 1D array or collection of instances of that type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to your question, but in my experience the best is to use a `System.Data.DataTable`:

```
Dim dtb As New System.Data.DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add("Column1")
dtb.Columns.Add("Column2", GetType(Integer))
dtb.Rows.Add("Z-123456", 2)
dtb.Rows.Add("R-125212", 11)
dtb.Rows.Add("C-254645", 25)
dtb.Rows.Add("R-456598", 96)
dtb.Rows.Add("M-456878", 35)
dtb.Rows.Add("O-980857", 89)
Dim dvw As DataView = dtb.DefaultView
dvw.Sort = "Column2 ASC"
Dim dtbSorted As DataTable = dvw.ToTable()
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtbSorted
```

Comment: It is not best to use a `DataTable` unless you're reading the data directly into it from a database. If you can otherwise populate a `DataTable` then you can populate a collection of instances of a dedicated type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - yes, it's possible to create custom classes and implement `IComparable` etc but DataTable is much, much, quicker and easier to code.

Comment: Why would you need to implement `IComparable`? The sorting is to be done by either a `String` or `Integer` property and both already implement `IComparable`.  You don't even need a custom class if you don't want, thanks to `Tuple`.  The code to create a sort a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer))` will be simpler than using a `DataTable`.

Comment: By the way, your example of sorting a text column containing numbers will only work if each value is the same length.  As you have it, "10" would come before "9" in the sort.

Comment: Ultimately I guess there are many ways to solve this problem. You are right about integer sorting - `DataTable` does support most data types for its columns (even custom types/classes IIRC), I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend the use of a `List(Of Tuple)` instead of an array. It is more dynamic. Please check this code:

```
Sub SortList()
    'Declare the List Of Tuple with a Tuple of Char, Integer, Integer
    Dim lstToSort As New List(Of Tuple(Of Char, Integer, Integer))
    'Example to Add items
    lstToSort.Add(Tuple.Create("R"c, 250645, 11))
    lstToSort.Add(Tuple.Create("C"c, 125212, 25))
    'Sort is just 1 line
    lstToSort = lstToSort.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Item2).ToList
    'Loop through the elements to print them
    For Each tpl As Tuple(Of Char, Integer, Integer) In lstToSort
        Console.WriteLine(tpl.Item1 & "-" & tpl.Item2 & "," & tpl.Item3)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit: Given your edit on the question here is the code fixed:**

```
Sub SortList()
    'Declare the List Of Tuple with a tuple of String, Integer
    Dim lstToSort As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer))
    'Example to add items
    lstToSort.Add(Tuple.Create("R-250645", 11))
    lstToSort.Add(Tuple.Create("C-125212", 25))
    'Sort is just 1 line
    lstToSort = lstToSort.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Item2).ToList
    'Loop through the elements to print them
    For Each tpl As Tuple(Of String, Integer) In lstToSort
        Console.WriteLine(tpl.Item1 & "," & tpl.Item2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know your comments

Comment: I am sure this will work. But I will use the previous answer in my solution as that provides me some secondary benefits.

Comment: This worked perfectly for a similar problem that I had!

Comment: @JerryT glad it helped you

Comment: Didn't know about Tuple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Public Function Sort2DimArray(SA As Array, order As Boolean, sc0 As Integer, Optional sc1 As Integer = -1, Optional sc2 As Integer = -1) As Array

    Dim cols As Integer = SA.GetLength(1) - 1
    Dim rows As Integer = SA.GetLength(0) - 1
    Dim na(rows, cols) As String
    Dim a(rows) As String
    Dim b(rows) As Integer
    Dim c As Integer = 1
    If sc1 > -1 Then c = c + 1
    If sc2 > -1 Then c = c + 1

    For x = 0 To rows
        If c = 1 Then a(x) = SA(x, sc0)
        If c = 2 Then a(x) = SA(x, sc0) & SA(x, sc1)
        If c = 3 Then a(x) = SA(x, sc0) & SA(x, sc1) & SA(x, sc2)
        b(x) = x
    Next
    Array.Sort(a, b)
    If order = False Then
        For x = 0 To rows
            For y = 0 To cols
                na(x, y) = SA(b(x), y)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        For x = 0 To rows
            For y = 0 To cols
                na(rows - x, y) = SA(b(x), y)
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Sort2DimArray = na
End Function
```